# Ubuntu server 20.04 ad-hoc network usb dongle

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, raspberrypi, realtek-wireless

I'm trying to setup an ad-hoc (mesh) network on Raspberry Pi 4s running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS - **through USB dongles**. The network does not need to connect to the internet (this is just to form an intranet). From a fresh install, I just add `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` and start my setup.

1. Install `rtl88x2bu` drivers for the dongles from this [repo](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu) (as per `README`, also seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018375/how-do-i-install-driver-for-rtl88x2bu) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu)).

```
sudo apt-get install dkms bc git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

2. Plug in dongle and setup the `wlan1` interface as per the [WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc#Network_Manager).

```
Set ip=192.168.1.1, netmask=255.255.255.0, blank gateway.
```

Note: I tried with and without `ignoring` `ipv6` as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62605/i-cannot-create-ad-hoc-wireless-networks-and-stay-connected-how-can-i-fix-this).

Note: the netmask is indicated as `24` if I close and reopen the `nm-connection-editor`.

My config:

[image: conn_config_wifi]

[image: conn_config_ipv4]

[image: conn_config_ipv6]

3. (I tried with and without this step) I bring down the other interfaces (`eth0` and `wlan0`) with `sudo ip link set [interface] down` - as the WifiDocs mention

> If you have more than one interface with link-local addresses there can be some routing confusion

I also tried doing all these steps by making a `NetworkManager` yaml, but I get the same results.

I can see the network being broadcast, but running a `ping` command fails - no error message, it just hangs until I `ctrl+c` and then indicates 100% packet loss.

I'd be happy with any solution that gets two Pis talking to each other via ad-hoc **through the dongles**, but especially a `NetworkManager` GUI (as seen) or a `netplan` because I've looked at them. However, any solution works.

If it turns out the dongles (which use `rtl88x2bu` drivers) are incompatible with this project, a confirmation that the setup was done correctly would be great so I can track down an `rt2x00` dongle as per the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers).

Logs:

[image: logs_lsusb_ping]

[image: logs_dmesg]

### Update

I found [this repo](https://github.com/phillymesh/802.11s-adapters) which has a list of 802.11s dongles for mesh networks. I'm not sure what the significance of 802.11s is, but since they put together a list I'm going to try setting some of *those* dongles up to see if it's a dongle issue or a config issue.

Comment: For a hotspot IPv4 should be set to shared

Comment: @Jeremy31 If I understand correctly, this would make my device into a hotspot, not a node in a mesh network. Setting IPv4 to shared does indeed make it a hotspot - but that's not the same thing (right?)

Comment: That might be correct, I remember an older version of Ubuntu using ad-hoc mode for hotspot and android phones would ignore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get different dongles working on `Rasbian Buster`, namely some `rt2800`-chipset dongles from [this repo](https://github.com/phillymesh/802.11s-adapters). **This seems to confirm a chipset issue with the `rtl88x2bu` dongles.**

I can successfully configure the network with the `rt2800` dongles using any of the methods found in the my old linked attempts.

In Raspbian they are plug and play, no need to install drivers - but this question was officially for `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` so I'll update once I get time to test it out on that.

Comment: Raspbian showed the same symptoms when using an `rtl88x2bu` dongle (and several other 5GHz chipsets) - hence the conclusion that it's a chipset issue.